# multiple array return using ajax() on success : jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, return

hi friends i have an ajax()of jquery that parse the xml file ,
create array on success and want to return multiple array on callback
is it possible if yes then how ? pls guide me guys.
this is my example code .

```
var arr1= new Array();
var arr2=new Array();
 var var1,var2;
function parseData(callback){   
        var cnt=0;
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"test.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success:function(xml){

                    var tempcategory= new Array(2);
                    var tempitem=new Array(4);                  
                    var1= $(xml).find('var1').text();
                    var2= $(xml).find('var2').text();

                    $(xml).find('result').each(function(){
                    var Id = $(this).find('id').text();
                    var Name = $(this).find('name').text();
                        tempcategory[0]=catogoryId;
                        tempcategory[1]=catogoryName;
                        arr1[cnt]=tempcategory;
                        $('#output').append("<br/>"+categories[cnt]);
                         cnt++;
                    });                 
                             callback.call(null,var1);

                error: function(){
                     alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
                }
           });      

}
```

**now in this code there is a line 
callback.call(null,var1);**

In this i m returning only 1 variable but like that i have array and some other variable also how can i return that all array and variable togather and if not is there any other way to return multiple array.

thanks

Comment: You have an unclosed quote mark.

Comment: pls ignore that this is just an example for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>What you can do is:</del>

```
callback.call( null, var1, var2 );
```

Also, see Harry's answer with the syntax problems in your code.

Note also that it is considered better form to use `var arr1 = [];` rather than `var arr1 = new Array()`, they are both equivalent but the first is shorter.

**Edit:** A much simpler way to do it would be to simply write `callback( var1, var2 )`. However, if you still want to use `.call`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for a full description.

**Edit:**

thnx for help and we can use it as mentioned in this answer 
 `callback.call( null, var1, var2, var3 );`  and call the function with

```
fun_name(function (var1,var2,var3) {        
        alert(var1);
        alert(var2);
        alert(var3);        
    });
```

Comment: ok thnks let me try this  i keep in mind the other thing u mentioned thnx

Comment: one more thing to ask can u pls write the syntax of callback.call() with paramenters

Comment: ok then how will i get this value  can u tell me i m calling this function in this way when i pass single variable--> var total;
  parseData(function (x) {
   alert(x);
        });

Comment: can u show me any link or any thing to implement ur callback( var1, var2 )

Comment: What variables do you need to pass to the callback?

Comment: Do you need to edit this answer or do you mean to edit the question?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error in your function I have corrected it Plz check it

```
function parseData(callback){   
var cnt=0;
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"test.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success:function(xml){
            var tempcategory= new Array(2);
            var tempitem=new Array(4);                  
            var1= $(xml).find('var1').text();
            var2= $(xml).find('var2').text();

            $(xml).find('result').each(function(){
            var Id = $(this).find('id').text();
            var Name = $(this).find('name').text();
                tempcategory[0]=catogoryId;
                tempcategory[1]=catogoryName;
                arr1[cnt]=tempcategory;
                $('#output').append("<br/>"+categories[cnt]);
                 cnt++;
            });                 
            callback.call(null,var1);
        },
        error: function(){
             alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
   });      

}
```

Comment: pls ignore syntax only the thing i m asking how to return multiple array and varialbe in same as i have done in this callback.call(null,var1); is it possible